# Laravel Relation : add an id from other tables

Tags: laravel

```
public function show(Request $request, $slug = null)
{
    $products = Food::where("slug_food", $slug)->get();
    $relateds = Food::orderBy("created_at", "desc")->paginate(5);
    $ratings = Rating::where("food_id", $products[0]->id)->count();
    $comments = Rating::where("food_id", $products[0]->id)->get();

    if(count($products)>0){
        return view("user.product", compact("products", "relateds", "ratings", "comments"));
    }else{
        abort(404);
    }
    
}

public function addComment(Request $request, $slug = null)
{    
    $products = Food::where("id", $slug)->get();
    $ratings = new Rating();
    $ratings->comment = $request->input('comment');
    $ratings->food_id = $products;
    Auth::user()->ratings()->save($ratings);
       
}
```

Error Code  :
Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '[]' for column `efoodies`.`ratings`.`food_id` at row 1 (SQL: insert into `ratings` (`comment`, `food_id`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (dsa, [], 2, 2020-10-30 09:07:37, 2020-10-30 09:07:37))

i want to insert a id of table food  and insert it into ratings table

Answer (score 2):

Based on your query I suggest that the ID in FOOD is your slug.

If this is the case in the definition you can direct set the Food entity itself

```
public function addComment(Request $request, Food $food)
{    
    $ratings = new Rating();
    $ratings->comment = $request->input('comment');
    $ratings->food_id = $food->id;
    Auth::user()->ratings()->save($ratings);
       
}
```

If it is not ..

```
public function addComment(Request $request, $slug = null)
{    
    $food = Food::where("slug", $slug)->firstOrFail();
    $ratings = new Rating();
    $ratings->comment = $request->input('comment');
    $ratings->food_id = $food->id;
    Auth::user()->ratings()->save($ratings);
       
}
```

PS.. Using the last line
`Auth::user()->ratings()->save($ratings)`
Doesn't sound ok instead I would just set

```
public function addComment(Request $request, $slug = null)
{    
    $food = Food::where("slug", $slug)->firstOrFail();
    $ratings = new Rating();
    $ratings->comment = $request->input('comment');
    $ratings->food_id = $food->id;
    $ratings->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $ratings->save();
}
```

At your route be careful using ?

```
Route::post('welcome/product/{slug?}', [LoginController::class, 'addComment'])->name("addComment");
```

This slug? may lead to empty slug and the how logic may fail.
It must be without ? to ensure that only valid request will go into containing that $slug.

```
Route::post('welcome/product/{slug}', [LoginController::class, 'addComment'])->name("addComment");
```

In case this $slug equals Food field that is not "slug" just replace the "slug" with correct name at first lines in my answers.

Comment: i use your first answer and i got an error that food_id column cannot be null
and when i use your second answer and i got an error undifined offset 0

Comment: @RizziqIbrahim can you try with 2nd + the PS comment I made to replace the Auth user line. This would work incase Rating table has a user_id for the relation to users ?

Comment: ok the $slug attribute is that ID , slug or slug_food by name  + what error you received

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'slug' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `food` where `slug` is null limit 1)

Comment: Can you show me your ROUTE from routes towards that action ?

Comment: Route::get("welcome/product/{slug?}", [LoginController::class,"show"])->name('show-user');

Route::post('welcome/product/{slug?}', [LoginController::class, 'addComment'])->name("addComment");

Comment: so it is slug ok, at the database is it called slug / id / food_slug ? It is good to use the same name for that route attribute as it is into the DB just to prevent mistakes.

Comment: undefined offset 0

Comment: when do you get that I don't have any offsets at the code  ?
At which page and when do you have it ?

Comment: i got error after delete ?

Missing required parameters for [Route: addComment] [URI: welcome/product/{slug}]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\kantin1\resources\views\user\product.blade.php)

Comment: at your blade "views\user\product.blade.php" where you make a link to AddComment you must set the slug
something as {{ route("name", $food->id ) }}

Comment: Offset 0 is where you set $products[0]->id > no products found no offset ..
Please read the laravel docs as you just don't know and understand what you are doing.

Using get() at models return a collection with all found rows. If you want single just use first() instead of get. Than products will be just $product and you can take its id and etc. Regarding the slug I told you ? shouldn't be used if it is a required field. 
Out of that I can't further help you with debugging your how app here.

Comment: ok bro thanks for helping 
I have finished my problem
thanks: